# How can I use tinymce editor outside moodle form?

Tags: editor, moodle

How can I use `tinymce editor` outside `moodle form`? In `moodle form` I can use `editor(tinymce)` as:

```
$mform->addElement('editor', 'title', 'Question');
$mform->addRule('title', null, 'required', null, 'client');
$mform->setType('title', PARAM_RAW);
```

But I want to use the `editor field(tinymce)` outside `moodle form` and fetch the value in it.

How can I do this? Please help me...

My **moodle version is 2.9.1**

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a text editor element on a page without using the moodle forms class?

Comment: @ConnWarwicker, yes you are right..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit of an awkward one, as Moodle doesn't really want you to use these things outside of their form classes.

But you can do:

```
$editor = \editors_get_preferred_editor(); // This gets the default editor for your site
$editor->use_editor("someidhere"); // This is used to set the id of the html element

// This creates the html element
echo \html_writer::tag('textarea', 'somedefaultvalue',
                array('id' => "someidhere", 'name' => 'somenamehere', 'rows' => 5, 'cols' => 10));
```

That will echo out a textarea element with the "id", "name", etc... you set and should apply the rich text editor to the element. To get the value out of that, you would just treat it like a normal form element, so if you submitted it through a POST request or something, you would just reference it through it's "name".

Here is a very basic example of a script that creates that element and shows you the contents when you submit the form:

```
<?php

require_once '../../config.php';
require_once $CFG->dirroot.'/lib/form/editor.php';
require_once $CFG->dirroot . '/lib/editorlib.php';

// Set up PAGE
$PAGE->set_context( context_course::instance(1) );
$PAGE->set_url($CFG->wwwroot . '/test.php');
$PAGE->set_title( 'title');
$PAGE->set_heading( 'heading' );

echo $OUTPUT->header();

var_dump($_POST);

$editor = \editors_get_preferred_editor();
$editor->use_editor("someid");


echo "<form method='post'>";
echo \html_writer::tag('textarea', 'default',
    array('id' => "someid", 'name' => 'somename', 'rows' => 5, 'cols' => 10));

echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' />";
echo "</form>";

echo $PAGE->requires->get_end_code();
```

Comment: can I use moodle filepicker in same way...I tried but no luck.

Comment: i am failed to get the value of textarea using jquery as `$("#someid").val();`

Comment: I'm not sure which it is in 2.9, but you should be able to access the value of it in javascript using either: $('#someid_ifr').contents().find('body').html() OR $('#someideditable').html()

Comment: Regarding the file picker, I've not tried it with that. The best thing to do, if you are using an IDE like Netbeans or Eclipse is to find a place where Moodle calls the filepicker and click through into the methods and see how it is doing it.